# How to resolve dependency version conflicts (NoSuchMethodError's)

Tags: java, dependencies, version, jsoup, nosuchmethoderror

In my Spring 3.0.5 Web MVC application I have defined a model class with a property annotated with @SafeHtml. When Spring tries to validate this model object, it blows up with the following:

```
HTTP ERROR: 500

org.jsoup.Jsoup.isValid(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/jsoup/safety/Whitelist;)Z
RequestURI=/guestbook/process-new-entry

Caused by:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jsoup.Jsoup.isValid(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/jsoup/safety/Whitelist;)Z
    at org.hibernate.validator.constraints.impl.SafeHtmlValidator.isValid(SafeHtmlValidator.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.validator.constraints.impl.SafeHtmlValidator.isValid(SafeHtmlValidator.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:278)
    ... (abbreviated)
```

I understand this is caused by my not using the right version of Jsoup. (I'm using 0.2.2) In this version I am using, the method signature for isValid() has changed or has been removed altogether. So to resolve this, I believe I should use a different version of Jsoup. Am I right?

Hypothetically, what if I wanted to keep using the version I am currently using - what is the other part that needs a change in version? Is it the Hibernate validator?

Also, can anyone suggest a way to find out *which* version of Jsoup to use? How do *you* usually resolve this kind of errors?

And, one final question, what does to "Z" letter at the end of the line mean? I sometimes come across other letters as well. What do these letters mean? Is this documented anywhere?

Thank you all in advance for helping me arrive at a better understanding of how these version discrepancies should be resolved, so I wouldn't need to waste so much of my time in the future... Cheers!

Comment: that's a good question. Yes, I am. So why am I getting this problem? If I don't define a dependency on JSuop, my app blows up with ClassNotFoundDef or something like that. I'd have to try again just to see. It's strange I have to define the dependency manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes
2. If you want to keep using Jsoup 0.2.2, you'd have to see if there's a version of hibernate-validator that will work with that version, which seems unlikely since I think the @SafeHtml constraint is pretty new, or you'd have to see if you can modify the source code to work with that version.
3. If you want a definitive answer to which Jsoup version hibernate expects, you can check the pom of whichever version of the validator artifact you're using. They're easily available at [maven central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22org.hibernate%22%20AND%20a%3a%22hibernate-validator%22).
4. "Z" is the type descriptor for the primitive boolean type. The VM spec has [a table](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html#84645) that lists the possible values.

Comment: oh, this is probably the most complete answer I ever got on SO. You've answered all my questions. The maven central link is excellent. I was looking into .pom files in ibiblio, but these contained only licence information (e.g.: http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/3.0.0.ga/hibernate-validator-3.0.0.ga.pom).

Comment: And thanks for the link in (4.). Finally the mistery is solved, and how simple it is... I just never came across this information. Thank you very much, again. Cheers